# Member function as parameter for a function template

Tags: c++, function, templates, callback, member

I want to register callback functions, and store them in a vector to call them. It should also be allowed to use member functions as callback functions.

My initial was approach was using `<functional>` in the following way:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;

struct Foo {
    void Bar() {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
void Register( T* obj, std::function<void(T*)> function ) {
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj ) );
}

void main(){
    Foo foo;
    Register(&foo, &Foo::Bar);
}
```

This doesn't work since the compiler cannot deduce the parameter type. It only works if I specify the type explicitly: `Register<Foo>(&foo, &Foo::Bar);`. This is not what I wanted, so I tried using the old function pointers:

```
template<class T>
void Register( T* obj, void(T::* function)() ) {
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj ) );
}
```

And it worked. Since I dislike this form of function pointers I made a type for Memberfunction pointers:

```
template<class Owner>
using Memberfunction = void( Owner::* )();

template<class T>
void Register( T* obj, Memberfunction<T> function ) {
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj ) );
}
```

This worked just fine. But now I wanted to support functions with one single parameter, since I didn't want to specify a Memberfunction for each parameter type I wanted to again use templates.

```
template<class Owner, class Param>
using Memberfunction = void( Owner::* )( Param );

template<class T>
void Register( T* obj, Memberfunction<T,float> function ) {
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj, _1 ) );
}
```

This worked good so far, but I didn't want to have to to specify a member function for one or no parameter, so I wanted to use `void` as second parameter of `Memberfunction`, but this lead to an internal compiler error, so I guess this doesn't work.

Interestingly `Memberfunction<Foo,void> bar = &Foo::Bar;` lead to the following error:

```
cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void)' to 'void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void)'
```

So now to my questions:

Is it somehow possible to use `std::function` for this?

If this doesn't work can I avoid having to specify at least two member function types?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm just curious, is there a reason you don't want to use `std::bind` when calling the `Register` function, i.e. `Register(std::bind(...))`?

Comment: That was also an Idea I had, but I wanted to make the function as easy to use as possible. And I think having to use `std::bind` to register a callback function is not as intuitive as just using the member function. I myself didn't know this for a long time and used lamdas to encapsulate the function call instead, which is not the best approach I think.

Comment: Well if you just passed the callable object, then it would be *much* easier for you :). Then it would also be possible to use other callable object like non-member functions or lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interestingly `Memberfunction<Foo,void> bar = &Foo::Bar;` lead to the following error:
>
> ```
> cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void)' to 'void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void)'
> ```

That's because your compiler is giving you a bad error message. The code itself is invalid, but it has to do with the the creation of the type `Memberfunction<Foo,void>`. You can use `void` as the parameter list of a function only in the special case that it's non-dependent. From [[dcl.fct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#4):

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type *cv* `void`.

I can write the type `void(void)`. But I cannot write the type `template <class T> using F = void(T); F<void>`. In this case, you're trying to create a pointer-to-member function using a dependent `void` type as the parameter list.

You don't need `std::function` though. Just fix your alias declaration to allow for passing in no arguments:

```
template<class Owner, class... Params>
using Memberfunction = void( Owner::* )( Params... );

Memberfunction<Foo> bar = &Foo::Bar;
```

---

That said, this doesn't make much sense:

```
template<class T>
void Register( T* obj, Memberfunction<T,float> function ) {
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj, _1 ) );
}
```

`functions` is a container of `std::function<void()>` -- that is, nullary function objects -- but `std::bind(function, obj, _1)` is a function that requires one parameter. This won't work. You'd have to pass in the float too:

```
template<class T>
void Register( T* obj, Memberfunction<T,float> function, float var ) {
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj, var ) );
}
```

otherwise it won't be nullary. Or, more generally:

```
template <class T, class MF, class... Args>
void Register(T* obj, MF mem_fun, Args&&... args) {
    functions.push_back(std::bind(obj, mem_fun, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make this work by hiding the type of `function<void(T*)` in a struct. This avoid the problem of non-deduced contexts:

```
template<typename T>
struct void_fn_type
{
    using type = std::function<void(T)>;
};

template<class T>
void Register(T* obj, typename void_fn_type<T*>::type function) {
    functions.push_back( std::bind( function, obj ));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7426f72ae33fb83)

I feel compelled to also recommend the use of a lambda instead of `std::bind`

(**Edit**: not sure if it's a non-deduced context in this scenario. Perhaps an issue with the fact that `Foo::Bar` is only convertible to `std::function<void(Foo*)>`)